# Running the getting-started xp0 docker compose with custom domain causes certificate issue

Tags: docker, certificate

When I try to do a `docker-compose up -d` with a custom domain for my local instance, the environment is created successfully but I get a certificate error when I try to load the site or the Identity Server:

> **This CA Root certificate is not trusted. To enable trust, install this certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.**
> **Issued to:** TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
> **Issued by:** TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT

[image: Certificate error (CA Root certificate is not trusted)]

### What I customized:

- `.env` file:

  - Updated `CM_HOST` and `ID_HOST` environment variables to custom domains
- `init.ps1` script:

  - Updated `& $mkcert -cert-file xp0cm.localhost.crt -key-file xp0cm.localhost.key "xp0cm.localhost"` line to use custom domain for Sitecore instance
  - Updated `$mkcert -cert-file xp0id.localhost.crt -key-file xp0id.localhost.key "xp0id.localhost"` line to use custom domain for Identity Server instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the certificate file names in the `.\traefik\config\dynamic\certs_config.yaml` file with the custom domain names you used when defining the `-cert-file` and `-key-file` arguments in `init.ps1`:

### .\traefik\config\dynamic\certs_config.yaml

```yaml
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: C:\etc\traefik\certs\custom.domain.sc.crt
      keyFile: C:\etc\traefik\certs\custom.domain.sc.key
    - certFile: C:\etc\traefik\certs\custom.domain.id.crt
      keyFile: C:\etc\traefik\certs\custom.domain.id.key
```

If your existing environment is still running, you will need to stop and clean it first:

```
docker-compose down
.\clean.ps1
```

Then you can compose it with these new cert file names:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: This was the solve for me but I had to do `docker-compose down` and `.\clean.ps1` a few times for my containers to all come up healthy.